# How to resolve the crash like 'NULL cString'?

Tags: ios, objective-c

there is a crash when I use `AVSpeechUtterance` to set voice. there is crash like **'NULL cString'**

to prevent the empty String, I judge it at beginning. the code is below:

```
- (void)speakString:(NSString *)string{
    if (SQ_Str_IsEmpty(string)) {
        return;
    }

    if (self.speech){
        AVSpeechUtterance *aUtterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:string];
        [aUtterance setVoice:[AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"zh-CN"]];
        aUtterance.rate = 0.53;
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 8.0){
            aUtterance.rate = 0.25;
        }
        else if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 9.0)
        {
            aUtterance.rate = 0.23;
        }
        if ([self.speech isSpeaking])
        {
            [self.speech stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryWord];
        }
        [self.speech speakUtterance:aUtterance];
    }
}
```

but we can still receive the crash report from some users.the crash log is below:

```
#28 Thread

NSInvalidArgumentException

*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString

解析原始
0 CoreFoundation    ___exceptionPreprocess + 228
1 libobjc.A.dylib   objc_exception_throw + 56
2 CoreFoundation    -[NSCache init]
3 Foundation    +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:] + 92
4 TTSSpeechBundle   TTSSpeechServerCopyVoiceNamesForLanguage + 15772
5 libsystem_pthread.dylib   __pthread_body + 128
6 libsystem_pthread.dylib   _pthread_start + 44
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib   thread_start + 4
```

and i find that the crash does not happens in the `main thread`

Comment: Which line is causing the error? What is the complete and exact error message?

Comment: @ rmaddy I have improve my question

Comment: Try `zh-Hant` or `zh-Hans` instead of `zh-CN`.

Comment: the crash happens occasionally , and there are only two same user crash.in addition, I need to use `zh-CN`.@rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

Is your judgment method correct? We use this in the string passing process.

```
#define SafetyStr(obj)     (obj == nil ? @""  : obj)
[self speakString:SafetyStr(obj)];
```